# How to create Person object for Google PlusShare.Builder setRecipients() method?

Tags: android, google-plus

I am trying to use Google+ sharing in my app to share content with a specified recipient.

To do this, I need to use `setRecipients()` - which looks like I also have to create a `Person` object for the current user. But there seems to be [very little documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/People#getCurrentPerson(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) available except from being told that the `getCurrentPerson()` method is now deprecated and that we should...

> use [GoogleSignInApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInApi.html) and [getSignInAccount()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInResult.html#getSignInAccount()) instead.

It looks like doing that will give me a `GoogleSignInAccount` object. But I already have such an object from the signing in stage.

So how do I get the current `Person` object from the `GoogleSignInAccount` - or from anywhere else for that matter?!

Here's my code:

```
Person currentUser = ???;

ArrayList<Person> recipients = new ArrayList<>();
recipients.add(PlusShare.createPerson("recipientId", "recipientName"));

Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(mContext)
        .setText(text)
        .setType(Constants.MIME_TYPE_PLAIN_TEXT)
        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(contentUrl))
        .setRecipients(currentUser, recipients)
        .getIntent();

startActivityForResult(shareIntent, RC_GOOGLE_PLUS_SHARE);
```

**PS - The answer is staring me in the face! Will post answer in a moment...**

Answer (score 0):

As shown in my own code :-/, I have already created a `Person` object like this:

`PlusShare.createPerson("recipientId", "recipientName")`

As required, you can create a `Person` object for the **current user** with:

`Person currentUser = PlusShare.createPerson(mGoogleSignInAccount.getId(), mGoogleSignInAccount.getDisplayName());`

...where `mGoogleSignInAccount` is the **GoogleSignInAccount** instance variable that can be created in your `handleSignInResult()` method - based on the [official example](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/).

If you're also basing your code on the official example, you'd just need to change...

`GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);`

...to...

`mGoogleSignInAccount = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class); // mGoogleSignInAccount is a GoogleSignInAccount instance variable`

Comment: what's the point of creating question and answering it few seconds later?

Comment: Because it may help someone else. Isn't that the idea? SO even make provision for it when you post a question - i.e., they appear to encourage it.